# Can I release an update for iOS versions not supported before?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, app-store

I have an app which was initially made for iOS 7 and 8 support.

After a while the difference between the way iOS 8 and iOS 7 was supporting layouts especially in working with container views, made me continue the support only for iOS 8.

Now I have some time and I'm thinking about remaking the app partially in a way that will work good on iOS 7 too.

The question: After my app became iOS 8 only on App Store, can it become iOS 7 and iOS 8 supportive again?

Comment: Yes, simply release an update

Comment: Just make sure to test the app on actual devices running both iOS 8 and iOS 7 before putting it in the App store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just set the iOS deployment target as 7.0 for both Project and Targets of your xcodeproj project.

Comment: thank you) didn't wanted to make a bad experiment and needed smb who knows this for sure)